# Manhwa in which the female lead returned to the past after the male lead killed himself

Tags: story-identification, manga

The female lead (fl) goes back into the past after having a tragic life. In the past life, she and the male lead (ml) met at a party and eventually became lovers. Then the fl's family kinda sold her so that she could get engaged to the crown prince. She ended up wanting to break up with the ml and they parted ways after spending a night together. The fl got engaged to the crown prince but the ml killed him so he could take her back. The fl got mad at the ml and the ml ended up killing himself in front of her. She also got pregnant because of the night they spent together and ended up losing it too, I think. That's all I remember from their past life.

In the current life, the fl still ended up getting pregnant, since she returned after they spent the night together. She also asked him if he wanted a child and he said no, so the fl ran away from him and her family, since her family wanted her to get engaged to the crown prince. She began working as a maid(?) and gave birth to the daughter (there's a time skip here and the daughter is like 7/8 after the time skip). As for the ml, he went insane because of the fl's disappearance.

The ml was invited to the residence where the fl worked (he didn't know that she worked there yet). When he arrived, he bumped into his daughter and noticed a similarity(?) between the fl and the daughter, so he asked the daughter who her mother was and confirmed that her mother was the fl. He then asked the owner of the house to invite the fl to dinner and the fl was nervous, because she was still trying to run away from him. They even had an argument in front of the daughter, which the daughter stopped after shouting at both of them for fighting. The fl was about to run away but the ml stopped her and she ended up giving in and they had a family reunion.

They all went to the ml's residence. They wanted to get married, but the fl didn't want it to be celebrated while the ml did. They ended up going with his idea.

The fl had long blonde(?) hair, the ml had short white hair, and the daughter had shoulder length white hair.

That is as much I can remember. I don't remember any of their names. I would appreciate if you could help me remember the name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is ***[Cierra](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/mr2gb5w/cierra)***.

> Cierra Elburke and Claude LeSpencer, both sharing backgrounds of illegitimacy, find refuge from the scorn of their family and society in each other’s arms. But when Cierra is forced to marry someone other than her beloved, she begs for another chance at life with a happier ending. Through the power of the “key” to the throne that is gifted by Claude, Cierra is given a chance to start over. Yet this time, she chooses to leave everything behind, including Claude, with hope for a better life. Has she made the right choice, or will this second chance prove more disastrous than her original fate?

The blonde-haired female lead, Cierra, and the silver-haired male lead, Claude, were nobles who met at a party and began a relationship in secret, but Cierra learns that her parents arranged for her to marry the first prince in order to pay off their debts. She spends one last night in bed with Claude and then tells him that they can no longer see one another due to her engagement.

The story skips forward a year, and Claude has now led a bloody rebellion to overthrow the emperor, in order to get Cierra back. Her father and others she cared about were killed during the rebellion, though, so she's angry with Claude rather than happy to see him, and in response, he pulls out a dagger and slits his throat right in front of her.

She then uses a magic key he gave her to regress back in time to the night they made love, one year earlier. They conceived a child that night and she decides to keep it this time rather than abort it, as she did in the previous timeline. The same night, she asks him if he wants a child and he says he doesn't, so she runs away, changes her name, and finds work as a housekeeper in another estate, where she raises her daughter, Blanche, as a single mother.

Eight years after Cierra ran away, Claude is invited to the estate where she works, and encounters Blanche, noticing that she has silver hair and blue eyes like his, and a face like her mother's. He soon confirms the identity of her mother, and although Cierra is initially opposed to a reunion with him, he eventually persuades her to return with him to his castle, where they get married.

[image: Image of Cierra in bed with Claude.] [image: Image of Claude meeting Blanche.]

Comment: yes it is!! thank you so much, been looking for this like crazy 